# hug create GET endpoint to download created word document

Tags: python, python-3.x, hug

I'm working with Python [hug API](https://www.hug.rest/) would like to create a `GET` API for the frontend. The frontend can download a created word document file e.g. via download button. However, after going through a [documentation](https://hugapi.github.io/hug/reference/hug/output_format/), I still cannot figure out a way to do it.

Here is my working script so far:

```
import os
import hug
from docx import Document

@hug.get("/download_submission_document")
def download_submission_document():
    file_name = 'example.docx'
    document = Document()
    document.add_heading('Test header', level=2)
    document.add_paragraph('Test paragraph')
    document.save(file_name)
    # TO DO: send a created file to frontend
```

I'm not sure if we can send the object right away or we have to save it first somewhere before sending the the frontend. (requirements: `hug`, `python-docx`)

I'm trying to use something like

```
@hug.get("/download_submission_document", output=hug.output_format.file)
```

but not sure how to return a file.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found a solution which is easier than I thought. Just do the following:

```
@hug.get("/download_submission_document", output=hug.output_format.file)
def download_submission_document():
    file_name = 'example.docx'
    document = Document()
    document.add_heading('Test header', level=2)
    document.add_paragraph('Test paragraph')
    document.save(file_name)
    return file_name
```

Return `file_name` already download the `docx`